# property x not found on object of type y

Tags: objective-c, ios5, xcode4.3

Newbie here, working on a programmable calculator.

In the interface of the model class `CalculatorBrain`, I declare

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *whatHappenedSinceLastClear;
```

Then in the implementation I also declare

```
-(NSMutableArray *)whatHappenedSinceLastClear
{
if(!_whatHappenedSinceLastClear) _whatHappenedSinceLastClear = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
return _whatHappenedSinceLastClear;
}
```

and then

```
-(double)runProgram:(id)whatHappenedSinceLastClear
{
NSMutableArray *mutableCopyOfWhatHappenedSinceLastClear;
if ([program isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]) {
    mutableCopyOfWhatHappenedSinceLastClear = [whatHappenedSinceLastClear mutableCopy];
}
return [self popOffProgramStack:mutableCopyOfWhatHappenedSinceLastClear];
}
```

But in the ViewController, when I declare

```
-(IBAction)testPressed:(id)sender
{
CalculatorBrain *brain = self.brain;   
brain = [[CalculatorBrain alloc] init];
NSMutableArray *program = brain.whatHappenedSinceLastClear;
[brain runProgram:program];
}
```

in the line `NSMutableArray *program = brain.whatHappenedSinceLastClear;` I get a message that says "property 'whatHappenedSinceLastClear' not found on object of type 'CalculatorBrain *'.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10527653/property-x-not-found-on-object-of-type-y-error-only-with-arc help?

Comment: Have you included CalculatorBrain.h in your view controller implementation?

Comment: Alas, I did include CalculatorBrain.h in the implementation, and I followed the suggestions but with no success.  :(  I'm going to post a follow-up question including most of my code in the hope that I've done something wrong rather than that I'm dealing with a bug, because at this point, when I'm still very new to this, not being able to tell the difference really hampers my ability to learn.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
replace:

```
NSMutableArray *program = brain.whatHappenedSinceLastClear;
```

by

```
NSMutableArray *program = [brain whatHappenedSinceLastClear];
```

and in brain.h

```
-(NSMutableArray *)whatHappenedSinceLastClear;
```

this should work.

Comment: There shouldn't be a difference, that just circumvents the problem.