# value assigned to a property in the model class disappears in the view/controller class

Tags: objective-c, ios5, xcode4.3

Right before my model class sends the variable `stringToDisplay`, NSLog shows me that it has a value.  But when I try to use it in my ViewController, I just get `(null)`.  Any thoughts about what I'm doing wrong?

(The good news is that, while working on this, I had sort of a breakthrough in understanding how models and controllers relate to each other.  I'm still a complete newbie, but I don't feel quite as lost as I did.)

Here's what I think is the relevant code:

CalculatorBrain.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface CalculatorBrain : NSObject
@property (nonatomic) NSMutableString *stringToAdd;
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSString *stringForDisplay;

- (double)performOperation:(NSString *)operation withArray:(NSMutableArray *)particularStackYouNeedToPopOff;
```

CalculatorBrain.m

```
@implementation CalculatorBrain
@synthesize stringToAdd = _stringToAdd;
@synthesize stringForDisplay = _stringForDisplay;
@synthesize whatHappenedSinceLastClear = _whatHappenedSinceLastClear;

- (double)performOperation:(NSString *)operation withArray:(NSMutableArray *)particularStackYouNeedToPopOff
{
<long code that I think doesn't matter because this NSLog produces exactly what I want it to:>
NSLog(@"%@",stringForDisplay);
return result;
}
```

CalculatorViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface CalculatorViewController : UIViewController
@property (nonatomic) NSArray *arrayOfDictionaries;
@property (nonatomic) NSDictionary *dictionary;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *variablesUsed;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *operation;

@end
```

CalculatorViewController.m

```
#import "CalculatorViewController.h"
#import "CalculatorBrain.h"

@interface CalculatorViewController ()
@property (nonatomic,strong) CalculatorBrain *brain;
@end

@implementation CalculatorViewController
@synthesize display = _display;
@synthesize history = _history;
@synthesize brain = _brain;
@synthesize operation = _operation;


- (IBAction)operationPressed:(UIButton *)sender 
{
NSString *otherString=[self.brain stringForDisplay];
if (self.userIsEnteringNumber) [self enterPressed];
NSString *operation = sender.currentTitle;
double result = [self.brain performOperation:operation withArray:[self.brain whatHappenedSinceLastClear]];
self.display.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%g",result];
self.history.text = otherString;
NSLog(@"%@",otherString);
}
```

And the NSLog in that last line of code give me `(null)`.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Technically, you should edit your previous question with the new information, if you can :)

Comment: Whoops--I didn't know.  Is there a way for me to fix that now that I've messed it up?

Comment: I know I left out some of the weak/strong things in the header files.  That's because I still don't understand weak and strong.  Maybe that's the problem....

Comment: You're going to need to cut-down the code to just include the appropriate bits; that's a lot of code to look thru...

Comment: Done, I hope.  I'm sorry about that--I err on the side of including too much code because I don't want to leave out code that's necessary to figuring out where I've put the bug--but there are so many places I put bugs that that ends up being a lot of code.  I hope this will do.

Comment: @JoelDerfner In this case you would ask a new question, because your problem changed. (In the first case you still had the same problem, but elaborated.) Just letting you know. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can guess that problem lies in the way you assign your `stringForDisplay`, eg.:

if you use something like

```
stringForDisplay_ = anotherString;
```

setter for property doesn't fire, so you have to retain your variable yourself otherwise it'll live just until your method finishes;

If so - use property setters, eg.:

```
self.stringForDisplay = anotherString;
```

that way ARC will do all the memory management.

Comment: Doing this _and_ tGilani's suggestion _together_ solved my problem!  Is there a way to accept more than one answer?  Anyway--thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Maybe I'm missing something but your property is declared in the class extension of `CalculatorBrain` so nobody outside `CalculatorBrain.m` knows about this property.

So if you want to expose this property to other objects, you will have to declare it in `CalculatorBrain.h` instead.

Answer (score 2):

Oh - your declaration of the property `whatHappenedSinceLastClear` isn't exposed to other classes that import `CalculatorBrain.h` because you put the property declaration in an `interface` extension in the `.m` file, which other classes will not see.

To make it publicly accessible move the `@property` line for `whatHappenedSinceLastClear` to `CalculatorBrain.h`, not the `.m` file.

Answer (score 1):

It really depends how you set stringForDisplay inside the `performOperation:withArray:` method.

for a blind guess, try using

```
NSString *otherString = self.brain.stringForDisplay;
```

after this line

```
double result = [self.brain performOperation:operation withArray:[self.brain whatHappenedSinceLastClear]];
```