# Variable not accessible, import provided in Xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I am having trouble accessing the variable, "megaBubbleUpgradeTier" from within my FirstViewController.m class. I attempt to access it here:

## FirstViewController.m

```
#import "FirstViewController.h"
#import "customTableCell.h"
//#import "RWGameData.h"

@interface FirstViewController ()

@end

@implementation FirstViewController
{
    NSArray *upgrades;
    NSArray *thumbnails;
    NSArray *descriptions;
    NSArray *megaBubbleUpgradeFees;
    NSInteger rowID;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Upgrades" ofType:@"plist"];
    NSDictionary *dict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];

    upgrades = [dict objectForKey:@"UpgradeStrings"];
    thumbnails = [dict objectForKey:@"UpgradeImages"];
    descriptions = [dict objectForKey:@"UpgradeDescriptions"];
    megaBubbleUpgradeFees = [dict objectForKey:@"MegaBubbleUpgradeFee"];

    _regularBubbleLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%li", [RWGameData sharedGameData].regularBubbleCount];
    _premiumBubbleLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%li", [RWGameData sharedGameData].premiumBubbleCount];

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [upgrades count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // Handles appearance of cells in table.

    static NSString *TableIdentifier = @"TableCell";

    customTableCell *cell = (customTableCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:TableIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        //cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:TableIdentifier];
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"customTableCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
    }

    cell.primaryImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[thumbnails objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    cell.upgradeNameLabel.text = [upgrades objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.descriptionLabel.text = [descriptions objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.regularCurrencyIcon.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"megaBubbleLarge30.png"];

    cell.regularBubbleCostLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", megaBubbleUpgradeFees[[RWGameData sharedGameData].megaBubbleUpgradeTier]];


    return cell;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return 78;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    rowID = indexPath.row;
    [self makePayment:self];
}

- (IBAction)makePayment:(id)sender {
    UIAlertView *messageAlert;

    if (rowID == 0) {
        messageAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Not enough bubbles!!" message:@"You need to collect more bubbles or purchase them from our store!" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"Buy", nil];
        [messageAlert show];
        NSLog(@"Cell ID: 0");
    } else if (rowID == 1) {
        messageAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Not enough bubbles!!" message:@"You need to collect more bubbles or purchase them from our store!" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"Buy", nil];
        [messageAlert show];
        NSLog(@"Cell ID: 1");
    } else if (rowID == 2) {
        messageAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Not enough bubbles!!" message:@"You need to collect more bubbles or purchase them from our store!" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"Buy", nil];
        [messageAlert show];
        NSLog(@"Cell ID: 2");
    } else if (rowID == 3) {
        messageAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Not enough bubbles!!" message:@"You need to collect more bubbles or purchase them from our store!" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"Buy", nil];
        [messageAlert show];
        NSLog(@"Cell ID: 3");
    } else if (rowID == 4) {
        messageAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Not enough bubbles!!" message:@"You need to collect more bubbles or purchase them from our store!" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"Buy", nil];
        [messageAlert show];
        NSLog(@"Cell ID: 4");
    }
}

@end
```

The problem is that [RWGameData sharedGameData].megaBubbleUpgradeTier doesn't seem to be accessible from within the class. Any ideas why? I can provide more information if needed. #RWGameData.h which declares the variable has been imported already in the FirstViewController header file, so it should be accessible in the corresponding .m file, FirstViewController.m.

The error displayed is:

```
Property 'megaBubbleUpgradeTier' not found on object of type 'RWGameData *'
```

## FirstViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "RWGameData.h"

@interface FirstViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *regularBubbleLabel;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *premiumBubbleLabel;

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *regularBubbleIcon;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *premiumBubbleIcon;

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UINavigationBar *navBar;

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;

@end
```

## RWGameData.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface RWGameData : NSObject <NSCoding>

@property (assign, nonatomic) long regularBubbleCount;
@property (assign, nonatomic) long premiumBubbleCount;

@property (assign, nonatomic) long megaBubbleUpgradeTier;
@property (assign, nonatomic) long bubbleFactoryUpgradeTier;
@property (assign, nonatomic) long bubblersUpgradeTier;
@property (assign, nonatomic) long mysteryBubbleUpgradeTier;
@property (assign, nonatomic) long bubbleBankUpgradeTier;

+(RWGameData *)sharedGameData;
-(void)reset;
-(void)save;

@end
```

## RWGameData.m

```
#import "RWGameData.h"

@implementation RWGameData

static NSString* const SSGameDataRegularBubbleCountKey = @"regularBubbleCount";
static NSString* const SSGameDataPremiumBubbleCountKey = @"premiumBubbleCount";

static NSString* const SSGameDataMegaBubbleUpgradeTierKey = @"megaBubbleUpgradeTier";
static NSString* const SSGameDataBubbleFactoryUpgradeTierKey = @"bubbleFactoryUpgradeTier";
static NSString* const SSGameDataBubblersUpgradeTierKey = @"bubblersUpgradeTier";
static NSString* const SSGameDataMysteryBubbleUpgradeTierKey = @"mysteryBubbleUpgradeTier";
static NSString* const SSGameDataBubbleBankUpgradeTierKey = @"bubbleBankUpgradeTier";

+ (RWGameData *)sharedGameData {
    static id sharedInstance = nil;

    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        sharedInstance = [self loadInstance];
    });

    return sharedInstance;
}

-(void)reset {
    self.regularBubbleCount = 0;
    self.premiumBubbleCount = 0;

    self.megaBubbleUpgradeTier = 0;
    self.bubbleFactoryUpgradeTier = 0;
    self.bubblersUpgradeTier = 0;
    self.mysteryBubbleUpgradeTier = 0;
    self.bubbleBankUpgradeTier = 0;
}

- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)encoder
{
    [encoder encodeDouble:self.regularBubbleCount forKey: SSGameDataRegularBubbleCountKey];
    [encoder encodeDouble:self.premiumBubbleCount forKey: SSGameDataPremiumBubbleCountKey];

    [encoder encodeDouble:self.megaBubbleUpgradeTier forKey: SSGameDataMegaBubbleUpgradeTierKey];
    [encoder encodeDouble:self.bubbleFactoryUpgradeTier forKey: SSGameDataBubbleFactoryUpgradeTierKey];
    [encoder encodeDouble:self.bubblersUpgradeTier forKey: SSGameDataBubblersUpgradeTierKey];
    [encoder encodeDouble:self.mysteryBubbleUpgradeTier forKey: SSGameDataMysteryBubbleUpgradeTierKey];
    [encoder encodeDouble:self.bubbleBankUpgradeTier forKey: SSGameDataBubbleBankUpgradeTierKey];
}

- (instancetype)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)decoder
{
    self = [self init];
    if (self) {
        _regularBubbleCount = [decoder decodeDoubleForKey: SSGameDataRegularBubbleCountKey];
        _premiumBubbleCount = [decoder decodeDoubleForKey: SSGameDataPremiumBubbleCountKey];

        _megaBubbleUpgradeTier = [decoder decodeDoubleForKey: SSGameDataMegaBubbleUpgradeTierKey];
        _bubbleFactoryUpgradeTier = [decoder decodeDoubleForKey: SSGameDataBubbleFactoryUpgradeTierKey];
        _bubblersUpgradeTier = [decoder decodeDoubleForKey: SSGameDataBubblersUpgradeTierKey];
        _mysteryBubbleUpgradeTier = [decoder decodeDoubleForKey: SSGameDataMysteryBubbleUpgradeTierKey];
        _bubbleBankUpgradeTier = [decoder decodeDoubleForKey: SSGameDataBubbleBankUpgradeTierKey];
    }
    return self;
}

+(NSString*)filePath
{
    static NSString* filePath = nil;
    if (!filePath) {
        filePath =
        [[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) firstObject]
         stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"gamedata"];
    }
    return filePath;
}

+(instancetype)loadInstance
{
    NSData* decodedData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile: [RWGameData filePath]];
    if (decodedData) {
        RWGameData* gameData = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:decodedData];
        return gameData;
    }

    return [[RWGameData alloc] init];
}

-(void)save
{
    NSData* encodedData = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject: self];
    [encodedData writeToFile:[RWGameData filePath] atomically:YES];
}

@end
```

Comment: What's the exact error Xcode reports?

Comment: @dpassage Property 'megaBubbleUpgradeTier' not found on object of type 'RWGameData *'

Comment: Possibly just an Xcode hiccup. See the answers to [Property x not found on object of type y error only with ARC](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10527653)

Comment: @JoshCaswell I will look into that tomorrow morning. In the meantime, if you want to sift through the code to see if there's anything I've overlooked that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Did you remember to add the line

```
#import "RWGameData.h"
```

At the top of your source file? If you don't import the header, the compiler doesn't know about the class and will think EVERYTHING is not found in the class.

EDIT:

Try changing this line:

```
+(instancetype)sharedGameData;
```

To read

```
+(RWGameData *)sharedGameData;
```

I bet that fixes it.

Comment: RWGameData.h is accessible. I can reference [RWGameData sharedGameData] it's just that in that specific function I can't reference the variables that stem from the RWGameData class.

Comment: Did you import the header at the top of your .m file?

Comment: I just checked and I did. :|

Comment: Just updated my program. I was confident that would work as well, but it did not. Any other ideas?

Comment: Nope. There's something not right about what you describe.

Comment: I looked into it a big more and I am able to access the variable 'regularBubbleCount' and 'premiumBubbleCount' derived from the RWGameData import but the other variables remain inaccessible. Any ideas on that?

Comment: Changing the return type of the method isn't going to have an effect; first because it's semantically equivalent, and more importantly, the compiler _already told you that it knows the type_ of the expression `[RWGameData sharedGameData]` when it said "...not found on object **of type RWGameData***" (emphasis mine).

Comment: @JoshCaswell, I noticed that after I posted the suggestion. I admit I'm grasping at straws here. The reported error doesn't make sense.

Comment: @JoshCaswell I deleted the derived data in accordance with what the thread you referenced was suggesting, but I am still having the same issue.

Comment: @DuncanC I went through and completely cleaned out all of the cache files, var files, etc. to make sure it wasn't an issue on xCode's end, then I realized that I can access the variable from another class called "PrimaryViewController." This class has an 'A' next to it as do several other files in my program. "FirstViewController" .h and .m files do not have this 'A'. Do you think that could be the issue?

Comment: Read up more on the whole 'A' thing and I don't think that's the issue...

Comment: I don't understand what yo are talking about with "the whole 'A' thing." You're going to have to provide a clear explanation of what you're talking about.

Comment: @DuncanC You can disregard the whole 'A' thing - I was referring to how certain letters appear next to files in the file navigator to portray their status in the git. A means that the file hasn't been committed or something similar. I've solved my issue. I created a new project and transferred over the code manually. I can only assume that something was wrong on Xcode's end which is what JoshCaswell suggested earlier, though I tried my best to clean the project but I must have missed something. Thank you both for your support!

Answer (score 0):

I created a new project and transferred over the code manually. I can only assume that something was wrong on Xcode's end which is what JoshCaswell suggested earlier, though I tried my best to clean the project but I must have missed something.